# Get $x$ from exponential aquation

Tags: analysis

how can I get $x$ from equation

$ e^{(\frac{-a}{x})}\frac{x}{a} - \frac{x}{a} = b - 1 $

I tried to play with logaritms but I had no luck. Can I even get $a$ from this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation in unsolvable for $x$, the only way is a numerical approach

Comment: I thought so, thx a lot